# Is it possible to represent a JSON Object with RDF?

Tags: json, rdf, jena, semantic-web, triplestore

Is it possible to represent a JSON Object as triples, using any RDF standard syntax?

I need to insert a JSON object into Apache JENA. So I need to convert A JSON object like:

```
{
"name":"John",
"age":30,
"cars":[ "Ford", "BMW", "Fiat" ]
}
```

Into a format accepted by Jena, the Triple Store.

Apache Jena accepts those formats (https://jena.apache.org/documentation/io/):

- Turtle
- RDF/XML
- N-Triples
- JSON-LD
- RDF/JSON
- TriG
- N-Quads
- TriX
- RDF Binary

Comment: Broadly speaking, yes this is possible. Given that your data is not represented in a standardized form, however, you will need to write the conversion manually, by mapping the JSON attributes and values to RDF resources (classes and properties).

Comment: Same question with 2 answers: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49365220/7879193