# RML Mapper for array of array in json

Tags: json, rdf, rml-rdf

I'm trying to map this JSON file to RDF, but I probably can not iterate correctly to get the values ​​of "value", which are inside the measures array.

JSON:

```
{
    "status": 0,
    "body": {
        "updatetime": 1528904042,
        "timezone": "Europe\/Rome",
        "measuregrps": [{
                "grpid": 1154218424,
                "attrib": 2,
                "date": 1528902698,
                "category": 1,
                "brand": 1,
                "modified": 1528902700,
                "deviceid": null,
                "measures": [{
                    "value": 7000,
                    "type": 11,
                    "unit": -2,
                    "algo": 0,
                    "fw": 0,
                    "fm": 131
                }]
            },
            {
                "grpid": 1154218987,
                "attrib": 2,
                "date": 1528902745,
                "category": 1,
                "brand": 1,
                "modified": 1528902747,
                "deviceid": null,
                "measures": [{
                    "value": 7200,
                    "type": 11,
                    "unit": -2,
                    "algo": 0,
                    "fw": 0,
                    "fm": 131
                }]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

RML:

```
@prefix rr: <http://www.w3.org/ns/r2rml#>.
@prefix rml: <http://semweb.mmlab.be/ns/rml#> .
@prefix ql: <http://semweb.mmlab.be/ns/ql#> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>.
@prefix fo: <http://purl.org/ifo/#>.

###### Fitbit MAPPING #######


<#FitbitRestingHeartRate>

rml:logicalSource [
    rml:source "provaJson.json";
    rml:referenceFormulation ql:JSONPath;
    rml:iterator "$.body.measuregrps";
];

rr:subjectMap [
    rr:template "http://ifo.com/{grpid}";
    rr:class fo:HeartRate;
];

rr:predicateObjectMap [
    rr:predicate fo:hasTemporalRelationshipToPhysicalActivity;
    rr:objectMap [
        rr:constant fo:AtRest;
    ];
];

rr:predicateObjectMap [
    rr:predicate fo:hasMeasure;
    rr:objectMap [ 
        rr:parentTriplesMap <#MeasureHeartRate>;
    ];
].



<#MeasureHeartRate>

rml:logicalSource [
    rml:source "provaJson.json";
    rml:referenceFormulation ql:JSONPath;
    rml:iterator "$.body.measuregrps";
];

rr:subjectMap [
    rr:template "http://ifo.com/{grpid}"; 
    rr:class fo:Measure;
    rml:iterator "$.body.measuregrps";

];

rr:predicateObjectMap [
    rr:predicate fo:hasNumericalValue;
    rr:objectMap [
        rml:reference "@.measures.value";
        rr:datatype xsd:float;
    ];
];

rr:predicateObjectMap [
    rr:predicate fo:hasDescriptiveStatistic;
    rr:objectMap [
        rr:constant fo:average;
    ];
];

rr:predicateObjectMap [
    rr:predicate fo:hasUnit;
    rr:objectMap [
        rr:constant fo:bpm;
    ];
].
```

Thanks for your help,
Chiara

Comment: Possibly you need something like `… measures.[*].value`. HTH: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49380987/7879193

Comment: I already tried as you suggested but probably it is not the right way to face the problem.

Answer (score 3):

1. Adapting the JSON Path expression allows RML processors to retrieve the heart 
   rate values. 
   For both TriplesMaps I changed them to `$.body.measuregrps.[*]` which iterate 
   over each `measuregrps` entry.
2. I added `a rr:TriplesMap` for each TriplesMap to make sure that an RML 
   processor knows that the RDF describes a TriplesMap:

```
<#MeasureHeartRate>
    a rr:TriplesMap;
```

3. All heart rate values where matched to every measurement. 
   I added a `rr:joinCondition` which only joins the heart rate value with the 
   right measurement when `grpid` values are equal:

```
rr:predicateObjectMap [
    rr:predicate fo:hasMeasure;
    rr:objectMap [ 
        rr:parentTriplesMap <#MeasureHeartRate>;
        rr:joinCondition [
            rr:child "grpid";
            rr:parent "grpid";
        ];
    ];
].
```

4. I changed the IRI of the heart rate measurement mapping since the IRI was 
   not unique which resulted into a loop:

```
<http://ifo.com/1154218987> <http://purl.org/ifo/#hasMeasure> <http://ifo.com/1154218987>
```

The new IRI format also supports other types of measurements besides the heart 
rate.

**Mapping rules**:

```
@base <http://example.org> .
@prefix rr: <http://www.w3.org/ns/r2rml#> .
@prefix rml: <http://semweb.mmlab.be/ns/rml#> .
@prefix ql: <http://semweb.mmlab.be/ns/ql#> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix fo: <http://purl.org/ifo/#> .

<#FitbitRestingHeartRate>
    a rr:TriplesMap;
    rml:logicalSource [
        rml:source "provaJson.json";
        rml:referenceFormulation ql:JSONPath;
        rml:iterator "$.body.measuregrps.[*]";
    ];

    rr:subjectMap [
        rr:template "http://ifo.com/{grpid}";
        rr:class fo:HeartRate;
    ];

    rr:predicateObjectMap [
        rr:predicate fo:hasTemporalRelationshipToPhysicalActivity;
        rr:objectMap [
            rr:constant fo:AtRest;
        ];
    ];

    rr:predicateObjectMap [
        rr:predicate fo:hasMeasure;
        rr:objectMap [ 
            rr:parentTriplesMap <#MeasureHeartRate>;
            rr:joinCondition [
                rr:child "grpid";
                rr:parent "grpid";
            ];
        ];
    ].

<#MeasureHeartRate>
    a rr:TriplesMap;
    rml:logicalSource [
        rml:source "provaJson.json";
        rml:referenceFormulation ql:JSONPath;
        rml:iterator "$.body.measuregrps.[*]";
    ];

    rr:subjectMap [
        rr:template "http://ifo.com/{grpid}/{date}/{measures.[*].type}"; 
        rr:class fo:Measure;
    ];

    rr:predicateObjectMap [
        rr:predicate fo:hasNumericalValue;
        rr:objectMap [
            rml:reference "measures.[*].value";
            rr:datatype xsd:float;
        ];
    ];

    rr:predicateObjectMap [
        rr:predicate fo:hasDescriptiveStatistic;
        rr:objectMap [
            rr:constant fo:average;
        ];
    ];

    rr:predicateObjectMap [
        rr:predicate fo:hasUnit;
        rr:objectMap [
            rr:constant fo:bpm;
        ];
    ].
```

**Output**:

```
<http://ifo.com/1154218424> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://purl.org/ifo/#HeartRate>.
<http://ifo.com/1154218424> <http://purl.org/ifo/#hasTemporalRelationshipToPhysicalActivity> <http://purl.org/ifo/#AtRest>.
<http://ifo.com/1154218424> <http://purl.org/ifo/#hasMeasure> <http://ifo.com/1154218424/1528902698/11>.
<http://ifo.com/1154218987> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://purl.org/ifo/#HeartRate>.
<http://ifo.com/1154218987> <http://purl.org/ifo/#hasTemporalRelationshipToPhysicalActivity> <http://purl.org/ifo/#AtRest>.
<http://ifo.com/1154218987> <http://purl.org/ifo/#hasMeasure> <http://ifo.com/1154218987/1528902745/11>.
<http://ifo.com/1154218424/1528902698/11> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://purl.org/ifo/#Measure>.
<http://ifo.com/1154218424/1528902698/11> <http://purl.org/ifo/#hasNumericalValue> "7000"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#float>.
<http://ifo.com/1154218424/1528902698/11> <http://purl.org/ifo/#hasDescriptiveStatistic> <http://purl.org/ifo/#average>.
<http://ifo.com/1154218424/1528902698/11> <http://purl.org/ifo/#hasUnit> <http://purl.org/ifo/#bpm>.
<http://ifo.com/1154218987/1528902745/11> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://purl.org/ifo/#Measure>.
<http://ifo.com/1154218987/1528902745/11> <http://purl.org/ifo/#hasNumericalValue> "7200"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#float>.
<http://ifo.com/1154218987/1528902745/11> <http://purl.org/ifo/#hasDescriptiveStatistic> <http://purl.org/ifo/#average>.
<http://ifo.com/1154218987/1528902745/11> <http://purl.org/ifo/#hasUnit> <http://purl.org/ifo/#bpm>.
```

**Note**: I contribute to RML and its technologies.